# Quitar caracteres de un array JAVA

Tags: java, array, string

tengo un problema con mi código.
Estoy tratando de quitar algunos caracteres de un array para que solo queden los primeros cuatro dígitos de la fecha sin el caracter "/" que los divide.
Sin embargo me marca error, al parecer no se están pasando todos los caracteres de un array al otro.
Agradecería su ayuda.

```
public class Ksks {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String arr2[]= new  String[4];
        String arr1[]= new String[4];
        String fechas[] = {"03/11/1103", "24/02/1991","31/01/1031","20/02/2002"};
        
        for(int i =0;i<fechas.length;i++) {
            arr1[i]=fechas[i].substring(0, 5);
               
                  
               
               
              for(int b =0;b<arr1.length;b++) {
                      arr2[b]=arr1[b].replace("/", "");
                 
                      System.out.println(arr2[b]);
                  }
```

Comment: Si quieres quitar todos los caracteres / de una cadena Intenta con ``replaceAll``

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que quieres quitar los slash para coger los primeros 4 digitos.
Puedes hacerlo de esta manera realizando un split para poder coger los valores que necesites:

```
String date = "20/02/2021";
String[] parts = date.split("/");
String part1 = parts[0]; // 20
String part2 = parts[1]; // 02
String result = parts[0]+parts[1]; // 2002
```

O tambien puedes realizarlo de esta otra.

```
String date = "20/02/2021";
date = date.replaceAll('/', '');
String result = date.substring(date.length() - 4);
```